# hover over cards with React using the useref hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have used a useRef hook so that when I mouseover to particular card then the opacity of the other card becomes 0.4 I have a figure out a solution to this but I am thinking this might not be best solution and its quite lengthy too. Feel free to recommend me best solution regarding this. Here is my code and i have used **bootstrap** to create the card.

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react'

export default function Cardss() {

    const cardOne = useRef();
    const cardTwo = useRef();
    const cardThree = useRef();

    const mouseOverOpacityForCardOne = (e) => {
        cardTwo.current.style.opacity = "0.4";
        cardThree.current.style.opacity = "0.4";
    }

    const mouseOutOpacityForCardOne = (e) => {
        cardTwo.current.style.opacity = "1";
        cardThree.current.style.opacity = "1";
    }

    const mouseOverOpacityForCardTwo = (e) => {
        cardOne.current.style.opacity = "0.4";
        cardThree.current.style.opacity = "0.4";
    }

    const mouseOutOpacityForCardTwo = (e) => {
        cardOne.current.style.opacity = "1";
        cardThree.current.style.opacity = "1";
    }

    const mouseOverOpacityForCardThree = (e) => {
        cardOne.current.style.opacity = "0.4";
        cardTwo.current.style.opacity = "0.4";
    }

    const mouseOutOpacityForCardThree = (e) => {
        cardOne.current.style.opacity = "1";
        cardTwo.current.style.opacity = "1";
    }

    return (
        <section className="container-fluid section-three">
            <h2 className="display-3">Projects</h2>
            <div className="row">

                <div ref={cardOne} onMouseOver={mouseOverOpacityForCardOne} onMouseOut={mouseOutOpacityForCardOne} className={"col-md-4 col-12 mb-5"}>
                    <div className="card cards">
                        <img className="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap"/>
                        <div className="card-body">
                            <h5 className="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div ref={cardTwo} className={"col-md-4 col-12 mb-5"} onMouseOver={mouseOverOpacityForCardTwo} onMouseOut={mouseOutOpacityForCardTwo}>
                    <div className="card cards">
                        <img className="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap"/>
                        <div className="card-body">
                            <h5 className="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
                            <p className="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div ref={cardThree} onMouseOver={mouseOverOpacityForCardThree} onMouseOut={mouseOutOpacityForCardThree} className={"col-md-4 col-12 mb-5"}>
                    <div className="card cards">
                    <img className="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap"/>
                        <div className="card-body">
                            <h5 className="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
                            <p className="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    )
}
```

Comment: No need to use React for something that is essentially part of the visual design. That's what CSS is for. Try something like https://www.trysmudford.com/blog/fade-out-siblings-css-trick/

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish using a combination of state variables and `onMouseOver` and `onMouseLeave` props.

Essentially, when the mouse is over a card, you store its index in the state variable, then have the class of the card be dynamic such that any index not equal to the state variable gets a class that applies the `opacity: 0.4` to that card.

Here's a [Codepen example](https://codepen.io/kwameopareasiedu/pen/NWxrKxG) illustrating this. I used `opacity: 0.2` instead

Answer (score 1):

To make the code less lengthy, let's first turn a card into a component.

> Components let you split the UI into independent, reusable pieces, and think about each piece in isolation.

```
const Card = ({ // I'm using default parameters here
  imageSrc = "https://source.unsplash.com/random/400x400",  
  title = "Special title treatment", 
  text = "With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.",
  ...props // pass the rest props to the wrapping div
}) => (
  <div {...props}>
    <div className="card cards">
      <img className="card-img-top" src={imageSrc} alt="Unsplash Random" />
      <div className="card-body">
        <h5 className="card-title">{title}</h5>
        <p className="card-text">{text}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

Then, to achieve the opacity change, you can track the active card (the one with mouse over) with state and apply CSS classes to style the cards:

```
// Cards.js

function Cards() {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(-1); // I'm using -1 to indicate no active cards
  const getCardClassName = index => {
    if (active > -1 && index !== active) return "fadeOut";
    return "";
  };
  return (
    <section
      className="container-fluid section-three"
    >
      <h2 className="display-3">Projects</h2>
      <div className="row">
        {[0, 1, 2].map(i => (    // or [...Array(3).keys()].map
          <Card
            key={i}
            className={`col-md-4 col-12 mb-5 ${getCardClassName(i)}`}
            onMouseOver={() => {
              setActive(i);
            }}
            onMouseOut={() => {
              setActive(-1);
            }}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}

// style.css
.fadeOut {
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

Here is a working example:

[image: Edit hover-over-cards-with-react-using-the-useref-hook]